# LINQ's Left outer join column selection

Tags: c#, linq

I have three tables from a dataset ds.

```
var test0 = from a in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
            select a["ID"].ToString();
```

test0 has the following values --

```
  [0] "8" 
  [1] "9" 
  [2] "11" 
  [3] "2" 
  [4] "1"

var test1 = from a in ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable()
            select a["SubscriptionID"].ToString();
```

---

test1 has these --

```
  [0] "25" 
  [1] "27" 
  [2] "4" 
  [3] "26" 
  [4] "5" 
  [5] "6" 
  [6] "1" 
  [7] "24" 
  [8] "23" 
  [9] "2" 
  [10] "9" 

var comTable1 =
  from a in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
  from b in ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable()
    .Where(bb => bb["SubscriptionID"].ToString() == a["ID"].ToString())
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
  select b;
```

---

comTable1 returns these values, which are correct --

```
   [0] null  
   [1] {System.Data.DataRow}  
   [2] null  
   [3] {System.Data.DataRow}  
   [4] {System.Data.DataRow}
```

The problem for me is that if I want to select the specific field, it will throw a message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." in comTable2 with the following codes --

```
var comTable2 =
  from a in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
  from b in ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable()
    .Where(bb => bb["SubscriptionID"].ToString() == a["ID"].ToString())
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
  select b["SubscriptionID"];
```

---

Why the left join in LINQ does not return other no null values?  Is there a way to avoid this?

I ask this because my codes need to continue the left join with other tables like --

```
var comTable =
  from a in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
  from b in ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable()
    .Where(bb => bb["SubscriptionID"].ToString() == a["ID"].ToString())
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
  from c in ds.Tables[2].AsEnumerable()
    .Where(cc => cc["ID"].ToString() == (b["GroupID"]??"null").ToString())
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
  select c;
```

Now I could not get anything from b and c.

Thanks!

Comment: oh my poor eyes :) Please format your code using the code formatting options (the little binary button in the editor)

Comment: format complete, my good deed for the day.

Comment: Well, that was fun. Four people editing the question at the same time.

Comment: David, Thanks!  I tried to format it for a few times but still messed up.
Matt, Thanks!  I learn the code formatting options now.  Will do it next time.

Comment: Robert, Cool edit.  Cool Icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well yes - if you try to dereference a null value, you *will* get an exception. Try this:

```
var comTable2 = from a in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                from b in ds.Tables[1]
                            .AsEnumerable()
                            .Where(bb => bb["SubscriptionID"].ToString() 
                                   == a["ID"].ToString())
                            .DefaultIfEmpty()
                select b == null ? null : b["SubscriptionID"];
```

Basically the conditional expression at the end will leave null values where there were no matches, and the subscription ID if it did.

In your bigger query, you'd still need to deal with the possibility of `b` being `null`. Do you *definitely* want a left outer join here, rather than the inner join given by a LINQ join clause?

Comment: Cool Jon.  That is what I need to know.  I want a left outer join definitely here for now.  By the way, your "C# in depth" is one of my favorite books.  I read it two times with hard copy and electronic copy.  Hope you publish more.